# How can we override the standard 'Login' and 'Reset Password' and 'Change Password' page with a custom visual force page

Tags: visualforce, community, force.com-sites, login

We have a community, wherein we have made custom 'Login' and 'Reset Password' and 'Change Password'page for the site users.

We have a requirement , wherein we need to show the same page for the standard Salesforce users.

I tried, searching for it implementation, but couldn't find any.
Help would be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: I think salesforce doesn't supports that level of customization. What can be done is listed here- [`Customize Your My Domain Login Page with Your Own Branding
`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_custom_login.htm)

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma. Thanks for your help. Actually our requirement deals with branding and custom behaviour of the login/reset/change password page. Any idea, how I can go about customizing the behaviour as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can only override the login, reset and password page for communities..